# Laravel Airlock route for authenticated + unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-airlock

I'm using the new [Laravel Airlock package](https://laravel.com/docs/master/airlock) for an app I'm building. I have
a route that can be accessible for authenticated and unauthenticated users.

In the controller I check if the user is authenticated with `Auth::check();`. My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('post', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts');
```

The problem is that if I make a request with an authenticated user (with a bearer token), I **can't** get the authenticated user in the controller (no idea why). And if I add the `auth:airlock` to the route, it's only accessible to authenticated users (not want I want).

How can I make sure I get the `authenticated` user in my controller if there is one ?

Comment: Tried `$request->user()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (Auth::guard('airlock')->check()) {
    $user = Auth::guard('airlock')->user();
}
```

If it does not work at first, try to specify the airlock guard in your `/config/auth.php` file.